# How to find the indices of a letter in a word?

Tags: python

I want to write a program to find the position of letter `e` in a sentence and print the output (indices) as a list.

This is my code,

```
def find_position(x):
    n=len(x)
    for test in range(0,n):
    if x[test]=="e":
    b=test

    return b

text="Helloe"

ans=find_position(text)

print(ans)
```

I am getting output as `1` which is wrong. How can I get the correct answer?

Comment: Also, how can I get the ouput as a list. for example like (1,4,5) , instead of
1
4
5

thanks

Comment: As soon as a "return" statement is executed, the function ends. That explains why only the position of the 1st "e" is returned. Start you function with pos = [] (THIS is a list btw; (... , ... ) is a tuple) then, whenever a correct index test is found, pos.append(test) ; at the END of your function, return pos.

Comment: def find_position(x):
    pos=[]
    n=len(x)
    for test in range(0,n):
        if x[test]=="e":
            pos.append(test)
    return(pos)
        
        
text="Helloe"
ans=find_position(text)
print(ans)

It worked, thanks a lot man

Comment: What do you think the right answer should be?  `1` is a perfectly valid answer to "where is there an 'e' in this word?"

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, you could try to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get (index, char) tuple at once, and check the char to get your desired index:

Notes - it's always consider better practice to access an item in an iterable *directly,* instead of using indirect way (eg. index). It's also helpful to use some *meaningful* variable names in the program to indicate it's purpose and usage. (*for the future yourself to debug* ... ;-)

```py
def find_position(S):
    
    indices = []  # for the result
    
    for i, char in enumerate(S):      # word is an iterable characters...
        if char == 'e':
            indices.append(i)
            
    return indices
    

word = 'Helloe'
print(find_position(word))

# [1, 5]
```

```py
# List Comprehension way  - more compact and concise, and more general

def find_indices(S, char):
    return [i for i, ch in enumerate(S) if ch == char]  # char to search

print(find_indices('banana', 'a'))
# [1, 3, 5]

print(find_indices('fountain of fortune', 'f'))
# [0, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code:

```
   def find_position(x):
       pos = []
       n=len(x)
       for test in range(0,n):
          if x[test]=="e":
             pos.append(test)
       return pos
    
    text="Helloe"
    ans=find_position(text)
    print(ans)
    # [1, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you, also do you have some suggestions for me ? I am new to programming and I am just getting started. How can i improve and do you have any websites or books I can refer to get started.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I found this site very useful for learning Python (do the full tutorial and exercises): https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can yield the index and print the return value as a list:

```
def find_position(x):
    n=len(x)
    for test in range(0,n):
        if x[test]=='e':
            b=test
            yield b

text="Helloe"

ans=find_position(text)

print(list(ans))
```